# Difference of using element selector for hide and click functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I am unable to understand why `$('#mdiv input')[1].hide();` does not work and at same time why `$('#mdiv input')[1].click();` works fine?

Firstly I want to know why? Secondly how to make it working without having the id of the element?

[Here is JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/samiciit/5h5vE/2/) to see what i am trying and what I need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you are converting the jQuery object to DOM element object which has no `hide` method, your second code works as DOM element object has `click` method like jQuery object. You can use `eq` method instead which returns a jQuery object.

```
$('#mdiv input').eq(1).hide();
```

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. I have to read some material to know good to be able to clearly distinguish between DOM Elements, Element id and jquery objects etc :)

Answer (score 0):

If you **not** want to select tags by id, you can use

```
$('input[name="firstname"]')...
// or
$('input[type="text"][name="firstname"]')...
```